# How can I select real elements that not an integer and rational numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation, selectionmove

I have a list

```
list = {2, -1, 3/5, (Sqrt[2] + 1)/3, Pi}
```

How can I select from the list real elements that not integer and rational? That's mean, how can I get

```
{(Sqrt[2] + 1)/3, Pi}
```

I tried

```
Select[list, Positive]
```

and get

> {2, 3/5, 1/3 (1 + Sqrt[2]), [Pi]}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {2, -1, 3/5, (Sqrt[2] + 1)/3, π}

Cases[list, Except[_Integer | _Rational]]

Select[list, (# ∉ Integers && # ∉ 
     Rationals) &]

DeleteCases[list, _Integer | _Rational]
```

---

*Result:*

> {1/3 (1 + Sqrt[2]), π}

Comment: The integers are a subset of the rationals, and so `Select[list, # \[NotElement] Rationals &]` is enough.

Comment: Thanks @Roman for spotting this.

Answer (score 4):

One way could be to use `Cases`

```
Cases[list, x_ /; Not[MemberQ[{Integer, Rational}, Head[x]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use `Select`

```
Select[list, Not[MemberQ[{Integer, Rational}, Head[#]]] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can add other Heads you want to exclude, such as `Complex` if you want.  If you instead want to select only `Integers` and nothing else, then change it to

```
Cases[list, x_ /; Head[x] === Integer]
```

You can add other heads as needed.